# SQL Query simliping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql query.
This query brings records which column_2 in (51, 14) and not in (54).
Sorry for my bad gramer. Here is the query:

```
SELECT t1.'column_1'
FROM table_1 t1
WHERE t1.'column_2' IN (51, 17)
AND t1.'column_2' NOT IN (SELECT t2.'column_1' FROM table_1 t2 WHERE t2.'column_2' = 54)
AND t1.create_time BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 25 HOUR) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
ORDER BY t1.create_time DESC
```

*t1 and t2 are the same table*

By the number of records which have `'table_name'.'column_2' = 2` increase, this query will lose its efficiency.
Is there a better way to simplify this query?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can `order by` slower your query? maybe it can

Comment: Please provide more information.  How large is the table?  How large is the result set returned?  What proportion of rows that have 51/17 also have 54?  Even after fixing the problem with the single quotes, the query as written should be returning 0 rows due to the `BETWEEN` clause which filters everything out.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  hank you for your interest. Almost 1k  data are created per hour. Just 1 percent of these have 17 (IT is not important which is 54 or 17). It's my mistake, I fixed `BETWEEN` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The current structure of your query already looks fairly optimal, but it might benefit from the addition of indices to make it execute faster.  Consider this slightly updated version, followed by the index definitions:

```sql
SELECT t1.column_1
FROM table_name t1
WHERE
    column_2 IN (51, 17) AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_name t2 WHERE t2.column_1 = t1.column_2 AND
                                                  t2.column_2 = 54) AND
    create_time BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 25 HOUR)
ORDER BY
    create_time DESC;

CREATE INDEX idx1 ON table_name (column_2, create_time);   -- for outer query
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON table_name (column_2, column_1);      -- for inner exsits query
```

The index `idx1` above can be used to speed up the `WHERE` clause of the outer query.  For the exists logic, we define a second index `idx2` which should let MySQL quickly lookup any `column_2` value in the table and decide whether or not it is a matching record.

You may run `EXPLAIN` on the above query before and after the tuning, to see what benefit the indices might bring.

Comment: ...t2.column_1 = t1.column_2 AND... part is not a good idea for my query but thank you for the rest.

Comment: `is not a good idea` ... actually, what I wrote above is a good idea, and maybe even the most optimal way of writing your logic.

Comment: Sorry, It is my bad. I didn't know how to use `EXISTS`. I edited the question. I use the same table in both queries.